# Ruby on Rails group_by (how to group events by month)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey Guys I am new to rails.  I have a controller that create events and I want to group them by month (the month of such event date).  I am using rails 4 here is my code.

This is my controller

```
def index
 @events = Event.all
 @event_months = @events.group_by { |t| t.due_at.beginning_of_month }
end
```

This is my view code

```
<% @event_months.each do |month, events| %>
  <h2><%= month.strftime('%B') %></h2>
    <% for event in evetns %>
     <div class='event-card'>
      <a href="<%= event.url %>">
       <div class='event-image'>
        <%= image_tag event.image_url(:normal), :class => 'eimage', :style =>  'width:100%;' %>
       </div>
       <div class='event-content'>
        <h1 class='event-title'><%= event.name %></h1>
        <h2 class='event-place'><%= event.where %></h2>
        <h3 class='event-time-date'><%= event.start_time.strftime("%B %d @ %I:%M %p") %></h3>
       </div>
      </a>
     </div>
   <% end %>
 <%= link_to 'Show', event %>
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %>
 <%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: And what is your question? What problem do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def index
 @events = Event.all
 @event_months = @events.group_by { |t| t.due_at.month }
end
```

Month Name in view is given by

```
Date::MONTHNAMES[month]
```