# Where with a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I have a table like this:

```
Calendar
 - date
 - description
 - userid
```

And I would like to get all the events of a given month of a user by it's userid.

So I know that to get all events for a userid is :

```
Calendar.where(userid: params[:id])
```

And I tried (as I saw in some post already in here)

```
Calendar.where(userid: params[:id]).where("date ~= ?", '%2016-12%')
```

So this should give me all event from the 12th month of 2016 but instead I have :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: date ~= unknown
LINE 1: ...endars" WHERE "calendars"."userid" = $1 AND (date ~= '%2016-...
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Is your date column datetime type?

Comment: Yes it is, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try "parsing" your column `date` to char using the `to_char` Postgresql function passing the column and the format you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM calendars
WHERE to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') LIKE '%2016-12%'
```

So, you can use [`ActiveRecord#find_by_sql`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class):

```
query = "SELECT * FROM calendars WHERE to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') LIKE '%2016-12%'"
Calendar.find_by_sql(query)
```

Comment: Yes this is it ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is here

```
def index
  @events = Calendar.where(userid: params[:id]).all
  @event_months = @events.group_by { |t| t.date.month } // month is a given name
end
```

Please see the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18862762/8175208

I think will help you

Comment: You don't need a .all after a where call.